# Is there a constant for how big a GB is in Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, math

Apple has [changed how they calculate KB, MB, and GB in Max OS X 10.6](http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-13727_7-10330509-263.html). Instead of using 1024, they use 1000.

My question is how to deal with this in my code? I'm trying to get the amount of space free, so I get the number of bytes via `NSFileManager`. When I go to display that to the user, I need to turn that into GBs differently depending on whether they're on 10.5 or 10.6.

Is there a built-in constant for GB size? (Or whatever it is you would call the 1024 number? ) It seemed a little silly to define my own.

```
## I'm currently doing something like this.
if (running10_6) {
    double gbConst = 1000 * 1000 * 1000;
} else {
    double gbConst = 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
}

NSDictionary *attr = [NSFM attributesOfFileSystemForPath:@"/" error:&error];
double bytes = [[attr objectForKey:NSFileSystemFreeSize] doubleValue];
double freeGB = bytes / gbConst;
```

Comment: You don't *need* to display the free space in Gibibytes on a Leopard system -- there's nothing stopping you from using the Gigabytes (=10^9 bytes) units on all platforms.  I can appreciate the desire to match the host system, but it seems unnecessary to me here.

Comment: I'm showing the user how much space they need to free up in order for me to do something, so it would kind of be nice to have it match their system.

Comment: Ah, OK. That's a pretty good reason to want to do it.

Comment: I don't believe it's something that's implemented in Cocoa; it's just a new convention used by most of Apple's utilities.  For example, Mail.app still uses mebibytes in 10.6.  I think your current solution is the best way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since OS X 10.8 / iOS 6.0, the new [NSByteCountFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSByteCountFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class does exactly what you want:

```
enum {
   NSByteCountFormatterCountStyleFile   = 0,
   NSByteCountFormatterCountStyleMemory = 1,
   NSByteCountFormatterCountStyleDecimal = 2,
   NSByteCountFormatterCountStyleBinary  = 3
};
```

Decimal/Binary are 1000 and 1024.  File/Memory are aliases for whichever one the OS uses for that measure.